# How to add a horizontal card carousel view to a flutter app

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Hello I am working on a instagram clone using flutter and for the feed I want the images to show up in a horizontal card carousel view for the posts of from the user you follow

here is the current feed code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'image_post.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Feed extends StatefulWidget {
  _Feed createState() => new _Feed();
}

class _Feed extends State<Feed> {
  List<ImagePost> feedData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this._loadFeed();
  }

  buildFeed() {
    if (feedData != null) {
      return new ListView(
        children: feedData,
      );
    } else {
      return new Container(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text('InstaGroove',
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "Billabong", color: Colors.black, fontSize: 35.0)),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: new RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: _refresh,
        child: buildFeed(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Null> _refresh() async {
    await _getFeed();

    setState(() {

    });

    return;
  }

  _loadFeed() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String json = prefs.getString("feed");

    if (json != null) {
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> data =
          jsonDecode(json).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      List<ImagePost> listOfPosts = _generateFeed(data);
      setState(() {
        feedData = listOfPosts;
      });
    } else {
      _getFeed();
    }
  }

  _getFeed() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    String userId = googleSignIn.currentUser.id.toString();
    var url =
        'https://us-central1-mp-rps.cloudfunctions.net/getFeed?uid=' + userId;
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    List<ImagePost> listOfPosts;
    String result;
    try {
      var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
      var response = await request.close();
      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
        String json = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
        prefs.setString("feed", json);
        List<Map<String, dynamic>> data =
        jsonDecode(json).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
        listOfPosts = _generateFeed(data);
      } else {
        result =
            'Error getting a feed:\nHttp status ${response.statusCode}';
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      result =
          'Failed invoking the getFeed function. Exception: $exception';
    }
    print(result);

    setState(() {
      feedData = listOfPosts;
    });
  }

  List<ImagePost> _generateFeed(List<Map<String, dynamic>> feedData) {
    List<ImagePost> listOfPosts = [];

    for (var postData in feedData) {
      listOfPosts.add(new ImagePost.fromJSON(postData));
    }

    return listOfPosts;
  }
}
```

I've done some research on google and youtube and I can't figure out how to add the card carousel to the feed part of my app. I'm still fairly new to flutter so any help would be amazing! thanks in advance!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. This is a sample image carousel screen. For now, there is hardcoded image list used, you can create dynamic list of `Image.network()` based on image list from api call.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestImageCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _TestImageCarousel();
  }
}

class _TestImageCarousel extends State<TestImageCarousel> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        PageView(
          onPageChanged: (id) {
            //code to handle page change
          },
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: getImageList(),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}

/*
Get image list to populate in carousel
 */
getImageList() {
  return <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1, right: 1),
      child: Image.network("https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg",
          fit: BoxFit.fill),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1, right: 1),
      child: Image.network("https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg",
          fit: BoxFit.fill),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1, right: 1),
      child: Image.network("https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg",
          fit: BoxFit.fill),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1, right: 1),
      child: Image.network("https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg",
          fit: BoxFit.fill),
    )
  ];
}
```

Now in this you can make a network call to get feed image list and bind list to `Image.network("src")`.You can also add a page controller to get automatic carousel effects. Add this images in `InkWell()` to get onTap listeners.